# Masonry + Custom Infinite Scroll + Responsive Grid Width = Overlap with other page content on page resize?

Tags: responsive-design, shopify, infinite-scroll, liquid, masonry

I am working with Masonry on a shopify demo store, where we are also using an adaptation of infinite scroll to load products instead of having to paginate them. This all works fine until I try to resize the page and masonry re-calculates the height of the masonry div. It does this but only includes the height of the elements loaded on first page load, rather than all the elements that have loaded on scroll.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $container = $('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
// initialize
$('#container').imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
});
// infinite Scroll
var pInfScrLoading = false;
var pInfScrDelay = 200;

function pInfScrExecute() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= (($("#product-list-foot").offset().top)-800)){
    var loadingImage;
    pInfScrNode = $('.more').last();    
    pInfScrURL = $('.more a').last().attr("href");
    if(!pInfScrLoading && pInfScrNode.length > 0 && pInfScrNode.css('display') != 'none') {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: pInfScrURL,
        beforeSend: function() {
          pInfScrLoading = true;
          loadingImage = pInfScrNode.clone().empty().append('<img src=\"http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0068/2162/assets/loading.gif?105791\" />');
          loadingImage.insertAfter(pInfScrNode);
          pInfScrNode.hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {
          // remove loading feedback
          pInfScrNode.next().remove();
          var filteredData = $(data).find(".item");
          $('#container').imagesLoaded( function(){
          filteredData.appendTo( $("#container") );

          msnry.appended(filteredData);
          });
          var newLink = $(data).find(".more");
          newLink.appendTo( $("#container") );
          loadingImage.remove();                    
          pInfScrLoading = false;
        },
        dataType: "html"
      });
    }
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log(($("#product-list-foot").offset().top)-200);
    $.doTimeout( 'scroll', pInfScrDelay, pInfScrExecute);
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= (($("#product-list-foot").offset().top)-800)){
      pInfScrDelay = 200;
    }
  });
});    

});
```

And here is a link to the demo page: http://sweetpea-bicycles.myshopify.com/collections/accessories

Again, the problem only happens when you make the screen smaller or larger to make the grid width change.

Answer (score -1):

You need re-call Masonry function again for next pages. You input that code after "pInfScrLoading = false;"
Example:

```
function pInfScrExecute() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= (($("#product-list-foot").offset().top)-800)){
        var loadingImage;
        pInfScrNode = $('.more').last();    
        pInfScrURL = $('.more a').last().attr("href");
        if(!pInfScrLoading && pInfScrNode.length > 0 && pInfScrNode.css('display') != 'none') {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: pInfScrURL,
            beforeSend: function() {
              pInfScrLoading = true;
              loadingImage = pInfScrNode.clone().empty().append('<img src=\"http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0068/2162/assets/loading.gif?105791\" />');
              loadingImage.insertAfter(pInfScrNode);
              pInfScrNode.hide();
            },
            success: function(data) {
              // remove loading feedback
              pInfScrNode.next().remove();
              var filteredData = $(data).find(".item");
              $('#container').imagesLoaded( function(){
              filteredData.appendTo( $("#container") );

              msnry.appended(filteredData);
              });
              var newLink = $(data).find(".more");
              newLink.appendTo( $("#container") );
              loadingImage.remove();                    
              pInfScrLoading = false;

                <!--INPUT IN HERE-->

            },
            dataType: "html"
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Good luck for you!